# SVG images is not showing in Nativescript

Tags: android, svg, nativescript

I am trying to use svg images for android in native-script. Here is my code

```
<StackLayout xmlns:svg="@teammaestro/nativescript-svg">
<svg:SVGImage src="~/images/app_settings.svg" height="250" width="250" />                        </StackLayout>
```

I am using [this](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-svg/) native-script plugin . However I am not getting any error. But the images are not showing in android emulator.

Comment: Hi @Soham, did you find any solution for your issue?

Comment: @phenric unfortunately no. Currently I am not looking at it as I have moved ahead with jpeg.

Comment: I finally found a solution for this issue

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved this issue on my side.

Firstly, I use this package from SergeyMell: [nativescript-svg](https://github.com/SergeyMell/nativescript-plugins/tree/main/packages/nativescript-svg). Those two packages are very similar since they both forked this same package [peoplewareDo/-nativescript-svg](https://github.com/peoplewareDo/nativescript-svg).

I moved all the SVG files from *App_Ressources* to an *assets folder* in the app folder.
Then I added this line in webpack.config.js:

```
{ from: '**/*.svg', noErrorOnMissing: true, globOptions: { dot: false, ...copyIgnore } }
```

Finally,

```
<SVGImage src="~/assets/file.svg"></SVGImage>
```

This answer is not a big thing but now it's working fine for my project. Some of the steps were already done and the big changes are the folders move. Perhaps Android ignores for some conditions some files from App_Resources.

I hope it'll help as it worked for me.

Comment: Great. Will try it later.